# Upload file using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have already check and search for same question and  there are lot of solution but no one is working for me so posing question here.

I am doing practice of selenium web driver. I am using this form for practice : http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/

Now , I have **3 issues** in that.

**1 - There are first 2 links called "Partial link test" & "List test" which I am able to click on, using "findelement", but I want to open both link in NEW TAB in same browser.**

**2 - I am not able to upload file. My code is not working for that element.**

**3 - How can I select particular value from dropdown of "Continents"??**

My code is given below :

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();


    **driver.findElement(By.linkText("Partial Link Test")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Link Test")).click();**


    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("Tester");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.name("lastname")).sendKeys("Tester");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.findElement(By.id("sex-0")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.id("exp-2")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



    driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).sendKeys("01/01/1985");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.findElement(By.id("profession-1")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



   **driver.findElement(By.id("photo")).sendKeys("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpeg");**
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   Thread.sleep(600);


   driver.findElement(By.id("tool-0")).click();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   **driver.findElement(By.id("continents")).click();**
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Please help to correct my code.

Comment: Could you please check that the new window is not in a different iframe

Comment: @SakshiSingla - Appreciate your time , there is not iframe. links open in window.

Comment: Yes first issue solved , but can you explain me that this line mean? Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN);

Comment: If you Ctrl+click a link in the browser, it will open the link in new tab in the same browser. Keys.chord - Simulate pressing many keys at once in a simultanewos manner(http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html)

Comment: Upload file: WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("myfile"));
        upload.sendKeys("/Users/sso/the/local/path/to/darkbulb.jpg");

Comment: @SakshiSingla - Ahh , great. So it means here is pressing CTRL + R key right? and if we press that manually it reloads page. Then how in code it works like Ctrl  + T??

Comment: File upload still not working. your given solution I already tried.

Comment: What error are u getting for file upload code?

Comment: Who is down voter? any issue with my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added the answers inline to each of your questions, below. Also, an advice, is to use Implicit wait only once at the top while creating a browser instance, as its scope is the whole class itself. So, once declared, then selenium will wait a maximum of that time, for detecting an element. It can be rather overridden by using Explicit waits for certain elements, if necessary [Please see this link for better understanding Implicit and Explicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits):

**1 - There are first 2 links called "Partial link test" & "List test" which I am able to click on, using "findelement", but I want to open both link in NEW TAB in same browser.**

```
    //Clicking and opening Partial Link Text in new tab
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Partial Link Test"));
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.contextClick(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

    //Clicking and opening Link Text in new tab
    element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Link Test"));
    act.contextClick(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

**2 - I am not able to upload file. My code is not working for that element.** 
The path of the  file must be like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("photo")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg");
```

**3 - How can I select particular value from dropdown of "Continents"??**

You can use **Select class** for that like below. It will select the option "Australia".

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("continents")));
sel.selectByVisibleText("Australia");
```

Comment: Thank you so much subh. All 3 issues you have solved for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Open link in new Tab:

String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("urlLink")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);

Comment: Yes its working now but m confusion is :  here it is pressing CTRL + R key right? and if we press that manually it reloads page. Then how in code it works like Ctrl + T??

Comment: We are sending these keys on the link(Ctrl+R). Which means: Ctrl+Click the link. If you notice, we are not sending click to the element. So, Ctrl+R is doing the trick